# How to specify runtime directory for Vite when running the dev server

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm trying to use Vite for a React project. I need to configure Vite so that when I run the dev server it places the runtime files in a particular directory (because the files are used with another runtime environment). The server config doesn't seems to have an option but I'm not sure if I'm missing something or it is in a different place.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible right now according to this repo discussion https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/6108

Meanwhile, you could run the dev command along with the `build --watch` command to have both, but it would get slower

`npm run dev & npm run build -- --watch`